# Bounty and reputation shenanigans?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

Just curious about an observation, because it just looks goofy to me.  Maybe it's nothing.

This question: [How to calculate the total time a user spending on an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6471695/719186) was asked back on June 24th and then a bounty of 350 points was placed on it by [Predator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/805543/predator?tab=reputation).  Those bounty points being subtracted don't appear anywhere in their reputation history, and yet, this user did get the `Promotor` and `Benefactor` badges at that time.

The accepted answer and bounty points were awarded to [Gens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670866/gens?tab=reputation).  Again, those bounty points being awarded do not appear in their history.

Last week, Predator "unaccepted" the Gens answer, offered a 500 point bounty, then two days later, accepted the answer again, and awarded the 500 points.  Maybe this was just a way of giving those points again if they were lost, but it's just a little weird.  Why do that?

I suspect Gens and Predator (and a third account [Sweety](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774411/sweety?tab=reputation), see [How to send response to asp.net webform request via other server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6390206/719186)) are all the same person or are family members, because it seems like half their bounties go to each other.  To what benefit this little game is not very clear, but anyway...

- How did that first bounty disappear?
- Is using the bounty system to transfer reputation monitored?

Comment: interesting observations...

Comment: You must have missed some guy who created an account that got tons of reputation in a matter of days by using an elaborate bounty scheme.

Comment: How do you know the original 350-point bounty was awarded to Gens (or, for that matter, offered at all) since there's no record of it?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Maybe.  The Sweety account offered a 350 point bounty on July 2 and there's nothing in their history that shows they had 350 points to give.

Comment: @PopularDemand Sad, pathetic story really.  The bounty ended on my birthday, and I was thinking I was about to be rewarded a birthday gift.  Instead, the bounty was awarded to a mostly non-answer.  I was soured on bounties for a bit.

Comment: Free detective work: I checked the `/revisions` history for all the posts and found no trace of the 350-point bounty. Superficially, the 500-point bounty looks to be aboveboard. Predator's badge list indicates that he earned Promoter on Jun 26 and Benefactor on Jul 2, but his bounties tab indicates that the 500-pointer was his only offered bounty and was offered in December. I have two theories, both pretty shaky. 1) Predator flagged a mod to undo the 350-pointer around the time it was awarded; 2) Gens's account was merged at some point, causing history weirdness.

Comment: Gens's bounties tab shows him earning the 500-pointer in December, but doesn't have a trace of the 350 pointer. Ah! But on Jul 3, Gens [lost 350 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/users/670866/gens?tab=reputation) with the comment "bounty"... even though the record doesn't show him ever earning that 350! I'm now leaning more towards "he awarded the bounty to his own sockpuppet, which was later merged." I see nothing related to the 350 pointer in Predator's history.

Comment: @PopularDemand The 350 Gens lost was on a bounty he placed on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506079/how-to-retrieve-strings-via-reflection-and-concatenate-it-ascending-ly), which they abondoned and was 1/2 community awarded.  But I do remember the quick turn-around of the 350 to another bounty as odd at the time.  I have no idea how SE merges accounts, but that might explain some of the missing evidence.

Comment: Dang, you're right, I misread something along the way, @LarsTech. (If it _was_ a merge, it could explain why no mod or dev has stopped by to explain things yet; as you probably know, they generally don't give out information about specific users/instances.)